# Построение схемы кабелей по фото

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, opencv, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

- Что имеется?

  Некоторый массив изображений на которых изображены преимущественно черные кабели, но иногда и другие.
- Что требуется?

  Необходимо сделать схематичное изображение кабелей из картинки, то есть чтобы вместо кабелей были изображены линии и при этом мне были известны их координаты. Координаты так же нужны не все, а лишь необходимые для схематичного построения.
- В чем проблема?

  Я попытался сделать это с помощью библиотеки OpenCV. Я смог получить наилучший результат так:

  1. Блюр
  2. Пороговую обработку
  3. метод Канни
  4. Контурная обработка
  5. Апроксимация контуров

Но даже так результаты являются недостаточно удовлетворительными. На фото видно что результат далек от схематичного изображения. В идеале надо бы объединить некоторые контуры в одну линию, но я пока не понял как это лучше реализовать. Так же на неидеальных образцах фото данный алгоритм работает совсем плохо выделяя ненужные области.

Возможно ли это реализовать на базе OpenCV или другой похожей библиотеке или придется использовать нейронные сети? Если возможно, то что надо сделать?

---

Исходное изображение 1:
[image: Исходное изображение 1]

Исходное изображение 2:
[image: Исходное изображение 2]

Обработанное изображение 1:
[image: Обработанное изображение 1]

Обработанное изображение 2:
[image: Обработанное изображение 2]

Comment: Насколько я знаю ИНС может классифицировать и то надо умудрится обучить ее.Или учить ее по кусочкам проводам?!Тогда должен быть фрейм сканирующий целое фото и работающий совместно с ИНС.

Comment: попробуйте бинаризацию и построение остова (скелета).

Comment: @Alex Alex Спасибо, помогла библиотека построения скелета.