# Автоматическая обрезка изображения

Tags: python, изображения, opencv

- Что имеется?

Некоторый массив фото на котором имеются кабели закрепленные на белом стенде (один из экземпляров будет прикреплен).

- Что требуется?

Обрезать изображение так, чтобы изображение было по границам белого стенда.

- В чем проблема?

Требуется автоматизировать процесс, чтобы каждый раз вручную не вбивать координаты границ стенда. Существуют ли готовые решения для подобных случаев? Если нет, то как подобное можно решить?

---

Экземпляр фото:

[image: Исходное изображение 1]

Comment: С использованием PIL или OpenCV можно провести пороговое преобразование и выделить светлую область

Comment: @MBo Каким именно образом это поможет? Как и зачем мне выделять светлую область?

Comment: Я так понял, что прямоугольник, описанный вокруг светлой (белой) простыни, и есть область обрезки

Comment: [Построение схемы кабелей по фото](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170242/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be)

Comment: @dIm0n тут ставится другая задача, хоть и пример тот же самый

Comment: Выложите еще пару-тройку типичных картинок, которые надо кропать.

Answer (score 0):

Бинаризацией выделяем светлую область, морфологическими операциями удаляем шумы:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

file = "xCEXQ.jpg"

original = cv2.imread(file)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(_ret, threshold) = cv2.threshold(gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel2=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(25,25))
open_image=cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel2)
y_nonzero, x_nonzero = np.nonzero(open_image)
crop=original[np.min(y_nonzero):np.max(y_nonzero), np.min(x_nonzero):np.max(x_nonzero),:]
cv2.imshow('crop', crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]